# Не могу понять как нужно дописать код, что бы добавленный текст показывался и исчезал, а при нажатии на кнопку 'Отобразить' снова весь показывался?

Tags: javascript

Как правильно написать мини-программу, которая будет содержать поле для ввода задания, а также две кнопки: *добавить* и *отобразить*. При нажатии на кнопку "Добавить" – задание добавляется ко всему списку, а при нажатии "Отобразить" – задания отображаются в виде списка под кнопками.

Также при добавлении задания появляется блок с текстом «Элемент был добавлен». Блок автоматически должен исчезнуть через 2 секунды.
Не могу понять как нужно дописать код, что бы добавленный текст показывался и исчезал, а при нажатии на кнопку 'Отобразить' снова весь показывался?

```
    <div class="pul">
        <h1>Список дел</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="task">
        <input type="text" name="list-items" placeholder="Задание">
    </div>

    <button class="btn-1" id="add">Добавить</button>
    <button class="btn-2" id="show">Отобразить</button>

    <div id="block">
    Элемент был добавлен
    </div>
    <ol></ol>

-JS-

$(function() {
        var toAdd = $('input[name=list-items]').focus(function() {
            this.value = ''
        }), block = $('#block').css({opacity: 0}), ol = $('ol');
        $('#add').click(function() {
            if(!$.trim(toAdd.val())) return;
            block.css({opacity: 1}).delay(1000).animate({opacity: 0}, 300);
            $('<li/>', {text: toAdd.val()}).appendTo(ol);
        });
        $('#show').click(function() {
            return;
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не силён в jQuery.. Вот такой вариант, если правильно понял задачу..

```js
$(function() {
  var toAdd = $('input[name=list-items]').focus(function() {
    this.value = ''
  });
  var block = $('#block').css({
    opacity: 0
  });
  var ol = $('ol');
  $('#add').click(function() {
    if (!$.trim(toAdd.val())) return;
    $('#block, #lst').css({ //Здесь добавил ol список для скрытия
      opacity: 1
    }).delay(1000).animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 300);

    $('<li/>', {
      text: toAdd.val()
    }).appendTo(ol);
  });
  //Здесь добавил отобразить скрыть для списка ol
  $('#show').click(function() {
    if (ol.css('opacity') == 1) {
      $('#show').html("Отобразить");
      ol.css({
        opacity: 0
      });
      return
    }
    $('#show').html("Скрыть");
    ol.css({
      opacity: 1
    })
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pul">
  <h1>Список дел</h1>
</div>

<div class="task">
  <input type="text" name="list-items" placeholder="Задание">
</div>

<button class="btn-1" id="add">Добавить</button>
<button class="btn-2" id="show">Отобразить</button>

<div id="block">
  Элемент был добавлен
</div>
<ol id="lst"></ol>
```